# How to get a list of the lines of code run during an execution?

Tags: java, localization, code-coverage, lines, fault

I've tried to search for this topic but I haven't found what I'm looking for, it could be that my terminology is off however. I'm writing Java and coding in Eclipse Luna.

I currently have a program, and a set of tests related to that program that will produce a pass/fail result for each. What I'm looking for is the ability to run one of these tests and retrieve a list of the lines of code (both in the test file and the actual program) that has been executed at some point during the test. What methods can be used to accomplish this? The idea is to use that list later for fault localization if a test failed.

Comment: you can use any code coverage tool i.e. **EMMA** . in this you can get line coverage, class coverage, block coverage

Comment: Thanks! I tried EclEmma and it works well with what I've tried to do so far.